# Modify the URL through an .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL which looks like

```
localhost/myapp/index.php?mod=user&page=createuser
```

I want the URL to look like

```
localhost/user/createuser
```

How do I do this with a htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.+)/(.*) myapp/index.php?mod=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /myapp/index.php?mod=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: `FollowSymlinks` isn't needed, is it?

Comment: Do I have to write this rule for every page? What if I have different mods and different pages?

Comment: what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: I would like the URL to look like localhost/myapp/[mod]/[page] and want Apache to access the URL localhost/myapp/index.php?mod=[mod]&page=[page]